# Wi Fi Problem on Ubuntu 16.04.1. Connecting and Disconnecting continuously

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1. From that point my Laptop not connection to router (DLink-DWR-116).
It behaves randomly.
Problems I faced:

1. Some time's it is connecting  by restarting network manager using command  :::: sudo service network-manager restart
   After that also the network  is not stable. suddenly disconnecting.
   2.Second trail: Switch off and On Router. After that also the network  is not stable. suddenly disconnecting.
   3.Suppose it is connected. Then after some  time it goes to sleep state. If I wake up again again same issue. Continuously searching for network.

Any one facing same issue and fixed it

Thanks,
Rajendra

Comment: Is this a brand new install of 16.04?  Are you aware that it will be EOL in 6 months?  I suggest to install 18.04 or 20.04 instead.  If the problem still persists at least it will be worth it to troubleshoot an OS that will last years rather than months. FYI 20.04 had already had its first point release 20.04.1 so it's a stable candidate for installation.  Also if you actually installed **16.04.1** this is a very old point release. You should obtain current, up-to-date installation media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Agreed. But some particular requirements are there internally. Means Hardware dependency related to project So how to make stable wi fi connection in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Any one give update om this ? I am using Dlink DWR -116 Router. Any Open source links ? I tried as my best.